# php laravel 2 routes for 2 submits

Tags: php, laravel, routes, submit

I am new to Laravel and wanted to just have a miniprogramm, that has 2 input submits with value a and b,
When I click on a there is a route to controllerX@function and when I click b its controllerX@functionB.
I do not want to change my URL. I know how this works in simple php (input hidden)
I couldn't find a documentation where this is explained. Can someone link it for me or answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't entirely a laravel question, but you can either use `hidden` inputs to send a parameter with value `a` or `b` to the same route, or use the `action` parameter of a `<form>` element to send it to a different route.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="a"/>
    ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This would be handled by a `Controller` function, such as `handlePost`:

```
public function handlePost(Request $request){
  $hiddenParameter = $request->input("parameter");

  if($hiddenParameter == "a"){
    // do something;
  } else if($hiddenParameter == "b"){
    // do something else;
  } else {
    // tampering prevention;
  }
}
```

If you did it with the `action` method, you'd have the form:

```
<form method="POST" url="{{ url("/action/a") }}">
  ...
</form>
```

and a function for each of these actions, `handleA` and `handleB`:

```
public function handleA(Request $request){
  // do whatever;
}

public function handleB(Request $request){
  // do whatever;
}
```

Lastly, you'd need routes to correspond to these actions:

```
Route::post("/actions/a", "Controller@handleA");
Route::post("/actions/b", "Controller@handleB");
```

That's a pretty broad answer, but should get you on the right path.